# The error is missing delimiter (.inserted). \end{frame} (\documentclass{beamer})

Tags: beamer

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{defi}
The class of symbols $\mathnormal{S^m}$ consist the set of
function $\mathnormal{ P(x,\xi)\in C^\infty(R^N\times R^N)}$  such
that for each compact set $\mathnormal {K\subset R^N}$  and 
all multi-indices
 $\alpha , \beta$ satisfying
$$\mathnormal{|D_x^\beta D_\xi^\alpha P(\xi)| \leq C_{\alpha ,\beta} (\big1+|\xi|)^{m-|\alpha|}}.$$
%where $|\alpha|=\alpha_1+\dots+\alpha_n $ , and $\mathnormal{m\in
\end{defi}
Formula (1) assigns to each symbol $\mathnormal{P(x,\xi)\in S^m}$
a pseudodifferential operator $\mathnormal{ P(x,D)}$ of order
$\mathnormal{m}.$ \newline
\textbf{Example}: The function $\mathnormal{p(\xi)=\sqrt{1+|\xi|^2}}$ is a pseudodifferential
 symbol of order 1. Where $\mathnormal{\big1+|\xi|^2}$ is the
 symbol of $1-\triangle$, and ${\triangle=\partial_{x_1}^2+\ldots +\partial_{x_n}^2}$ is Laplace operator. 
\end{frame}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: And please have a look at [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: The problem is with `\big` you are using (twice) without delimiter.

Comment: this \big tomake 1 big if i dont put or if insert .  it look small. so my question how do i make it look big?

Comment: @EhabJad, don't use `\mathnormal`.

Comment: other letter like x will not show like math type

Comment: I think that what you want is to use math serif fonts for beamer slides. Search for it.

Comment: @Sigur Would you like to write an answer about the missing delimiter?

Comment: @samcarter, done.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the command `\big` which you are using (twice) without delimiter as argument.

When you want to change the size of delimiters, you can use `\bigl \bigr` but you must give which delimiter you want. For example:

```
\bigl( \bigr) \bigl[ \bigr] \bigl\{ \bigr\}
```

No problem mixing it:

```
\bigl( \bigr\} \bigl( \bigr] \bigl\{ \bigr]
```